# PHP insert array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a 5 tables like this:

prices:

```
priceList_id    product_id  compType_id     price   range_id
```

priceList:

```
id  name
```

products:

```
 id     product_desc
```

companyType:

```
 id     type
```

pricesRange:

```
 id     range_desc
```

the prices table is where i store everything and link with the other tables ids like this:

```
id  priceList_id    product_id  compType_id     price   range_id
 1      1                1           5          23.10      1
 2      1                1           5          21.30      2
```

The problem is when i recive the data and try to insert it to the DB:

```
<input name=\"price[]\" type=\"number\" min=\"0\" required>
<input name=\"price[]\" type=\"number\" min=\"0\" required>
<input name=\"price[]\" type=\"number\" min=\"0\" required>
<input name=\"price[]\" type=\"number\" min=\"0\" required>
<input name=\"price[]\" type=\"number\" min=\"0\" required>
```

i get the post like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["createPriceList"])) {
            $this->createPriceList($_POST["price"]);
        }
```

So $_POST["price"] is an array. How can i insert the data into the price table knowing that the 1st input is product_id: 1, compType_id: 5, range_id: 1. the 2nd input is product_id: 1, compType_id: 5, range_id: 2 and the 3rd input is product_id: 1, compType_id: 5, range_id: 3 and so on...
There are 6 range_id´s, 4 products_id´s and 5 compType_id`s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does anyone know what `createPriceList()` does?

Comment: createPriceList() is the function to insert the data into the db.
I dont know how to insert the data from the array

Comment: Could you show us fine people what this array looks like? That description is not very helpful. `print_r($_POST["price"]);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, with this structure. You'd have to include the "link" ids in your HTML, so you CAN identify which input is which. The simplest way to do that would be something like

```
<input name="price[1] type="number" value="10" />
<input name="price[42] type="number" value="500" />
```

etc... You CAN specify array keys via this, and don't have to accept the auto-generated keys PHP produces when your field simply has `[]`.

Then it's just a matter of:

```
foreach($_POST['price'] AS $id => $value) {
   ....  // 1->10, 42->500, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make createPriceList function with parameter in the form of array to insert in prices table

```
function createPriceList($price)
{
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($price);$i++)
    {
         $query = "insert into prices values($price[0],$price[1],$price[2],$price[3],$price[4])";
         mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Feel free to comment.